# How to filter android build based on hardware specification/GPU

Tags: android, apk, gpu

We got a great game on android market. But number of people reporting game getting crashed on their devices. Its turnout all those users using "Adreno 200 GPU" pretty old gpu. How can we filter users to stop installing this build?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using NDK? You can put in checks for processor type in that.

Comment: Yes. But I want to filter(something in manifest) so that users will not able to download the app.

Comment: I don't think its possible to specify that in the manifest. You must detect the CPU/GPU and degrade the app gracefully or alert the user rather than letting the app crash. Adreno is for Qualcomm platform only, by tying onto that you are limiting the reach of your app. You must support other GPUs as well or degrade gracefully.